# Keep 3D object on screen even after Image target lost in VUFORIA and UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am creating AR app in which I have 10 Image targets( only 1 recognition at one time). I want to keep the 3D object to be retained even after Target image is lost and update the 3D model after it again found image target (same / or different target)...

I have done so many things like parent change,coroutine, Invoke but none seems to work..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the object from disappearing when target is lost. Simply change the DefaultTrackableEventHandler in the (EDIT) OnTrackingLost method to do nothing.

That will result in your model hanging in the middle of the screen if you lose it fast enough. Of you move away from the target slowly, model gets to the edge and it may be that the tracking gets lost while out of screen.

EDIT:

```
void OnTrackingFound(){
   TrackerObject[] trackers = FindObjectsOfType<TrackerObject>()
   foreach(var t in trackers){ t.SetOff();}
   this.gameObject.GetComponent<TrackerObject>().SetOn();
}
```

then you have this TrackerObject component that is attached to all ImageTarget. It has SetOn/Off methods to do what it says.

You can make the code better with storing the info instead of looking for them each time.

Comment: I did this.. but in that case all the 10 3D models appeared in camera view ..as in my scene view these are very close

Comment: i think u r saying on "OnTrackingLost()" instead of OnTrackingFound

Comment: Oops indeed yes.

Comment: if OnTrackingLost() commented then all the models already tracked remain in scene ... but i want only last one tracked...
i think its with TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus and previous status..but i"m not able to make logic

Comment: When you find a new marker, disable all others.  When you lose that marker, only the last one is left as you disable all others when you found that one. Makes sense?

Comment: yes...exactly this is I want..I want last object on screen ..but if ontrackinglost is commented all the markers which are already found remains in scene... i want rendrind off for ohers but not which one is currently tracked...few lines of code :

Comment: `public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                   TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                   TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
        {
   if (previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.UNKNOWN &&
       newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NOT_FOUND) {
//firsttime = true;
   }
            if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
            {OnTrackingFound();
`

Comment: `//OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status.UNKNOWN,TrackableBehaviour.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    //OnTrackableStateChanged (default(TrackableBehaviour.Status), TrackableBehaviour.Status.UNDEFINED);
            }
   else if (previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED &&
    newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NOT_FOUND)
            {
    //Invoke("TrackingLost",5);
    //OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status.UNKNOWN,TrackableBehaviour.Status.NOT_FOUND);
  }
    `

Comment: `else
//   {if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NOT_FOUND) {
//     
//     asrc.Stop ();
//     bg.UnPause ();
//    } else {
//    Debug.Log("lost new status :" + newStatus);
//    Debug.Log("lost previous status :" + previousStatus);
//
//     OnTrackingLost ();
//    }
   {
    Debug.Log("lost new status :" + newStatus);
        Debug.Log("lost previous status :" + previousStatus);

    OnTrackingLost();
    //OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status.UNKNOWN,TrackableBehaviour.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    }
        }`

Comment: please have a look ... not getting any solution

Comment: Oh... I have not seen that... Thanks will try that and tell you

Comment: TrackerObject  not found in class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour,ITrackableEventHandler

Comment: You need to create that class with the SetOn/Off implementation and attach it to each image target object.

Comment: Sir...please help... Not able to do

Comment: I almost completed my project..but still this issue remained unsolved... could u explain your answer ?

Comment: in setoff method what I supposed to do off 3DModel rendering or SetActive false. As in rendering it gives `Exception in callback: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> UnityEngine.MissingComponentException: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the "3dObject" game object, but a script is trying to access it.`<br>please see question [QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093738/how-to-make-my-3d-gameobject-invisible-if-no-renderer-attached-in-unity)

Answer (score 0):

Just enable **Extended Tracking** from Inspector menu . 
For Example :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take the position and orientation of the detected object when Vuforia Target is there and then you can Instantiate the same object as:

```
GameObject generatedObj = Instantiate(mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject, new  Vector3(0,-4.0f,18), Quaternion.identity);
generatedObj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1); // change its local scale in x y z format
generatedObj.AddComponent<Translate>();
```

After doing so disable the ImageTarget from scene and enable again when you want it to be depedent on Marker.
But this has the limitation that
World co-ordinate experience will not be experienced,it will be like
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHhMCdh3k7U

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don´t have enable the option "Track Device Pose" in Vuforia Engine Configuration in ARCamera object, this option cause object keep in screen.

Disable "Track Device Pose" and this resolve the issue.

Unity 2018.3.6 With Vuforia 7