# how to make my 3D Gameobject invisible if no renderer attached in UNITY?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, renderer

I have 3D object and I want to make it **invisible by turning off its rendering**. But when I run the code in runtime it shows :: 
*" Exception in callback: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> UnityEngine.MissingComponentException: **There is no 'Renderer' attached to the "3dObject" game object, but a script is trying to access it.***"
I want to know if There is no renderer then how I am able to see that object in scene/game view. and also in inspector nothing is there (mesh renderer / renderer / mesh filter).
I'm Using **c#** : `this.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled=true;`
I'm using **vuforia** and want to keep last tracked object on screen after Tracking Lost function is called. 
**OR** Is there any other way to do this...?

I'm new in unity and I know its a pretty basic question but not getting anything. Need Help..
[image]

Comment: I dont see a mesh renderer component in the attachment. 'this.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled=true;' will get renderer component only on this gameobject, not on the child gameobjects. I think your renderer is on the mesh (mesh filter) which is also not present here.

Comment: any renderer is not present still it is there in scene/game view.. how its possible ..I'm not getting. I just Import a .fbx file from asset store. But in inspector no renderer is there. HOW ?

Comment: @Nitesh Because one (or more) of that game object's children has a MeshRenderer attached.

Comment: sorry ..in this model there is a long child list and one of them is having skinned mesh renderer.
Now my doubts are clear. but one thing, how to access all the renderers present on child of that particular 3D Model<br> I,m using :: `Renderer[] ren = this.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be:

1. Create a new layer called: InvisibleGO.
2. Set the layer of your GameObject to be InvisibleGO
3. Then you can set the culling mask
       for the camera on each camera to only display the layers that you
       want:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html

Comment: I'm making augmented reality app using vuforia , so I have prefab AR Camera ..not sure this thing works without affecting project.But approach is good for other projects.. will learn something from this .. Thanks !